# Open source Google analytics lib for android

Tags: android, google-analytics

I need to report some events from my android app to GA, but main requirement is not to use API lib in dependencies - all analytics-related code should be encapsulated in my app package (actually it is not an app, but SDK). So I'm looking for some pieces of code for constructing Google Analytics API queries. Can anyone advice something?

Comment: 1st I must say that is a really bizarre requirement to say the least. But probably the best way to start is check how GA is implemented for websites, what are the scrips they use and HTTP REQUESTS they send.

Comment: I totally agree about "bizarre requirement", but this is a requirement. Reverse engineering is always a solution, but I'm looking for simpler way :) For now I'm playing with [JarJar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) to mask Google Android GA SDK.

Answer (score 2):

See [Manually sending data to Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653239/manually-sending-data-to-google-analytics/12658259#12658259)

A Java library (designed for desktops, but it should probably work in Android) can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/jgoogleanalytics/