# How to map object to proper query string for google analytics event in c#?

Tags: c#, google-analytics

I need to send google analytics event from the server but can not find documentation on how to map the object properly.

I need to send event like this

```
 {
  "event": "nameOfEvent",
  "ecommerce": {
    "currencyCode": "eur",
    "purchase": {
      "actionField": {
        "id": "9d9e3cc9-0007-4aaa-d986-08d6g2f07b63",
        "affiliation": "",
        "revenue": 100
      },
      "products": [
        {
          "name": "Product name",
          "id": "id",
          "price": 200,
          "category": "Category",
          "variant": "Buy online",
          "quantity": "1",
          "dimension1": "1",
          "dimension2": "2",
          "dimension3": "3"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Result should be similar to `https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect?v=1&t=event&tid=UA-222-1&uid=1&el=nameOfEvent&` here I have a problem, what to do next???
I would appreciate any help with it!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a possible duplicate of this. [Manually sending data to Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653239/manually-sending-data-to-google-analytics).

The above post has references to C# implementation of the Google measurement protocol https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide.

Comment: I have updated question, can you explain how to send event like in a question?